# How to disable production/research recommendations in Civilization IV BtS?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

Is there a way to turn off the adviser's recommendations for research plans and city production?

I already disabled the Sid's tips and tutorial advice in game settings, but the two 'recommended' technologies or units/buildings still pop up at the top of the research/production list. This at times can be really disturbing, as it frequently attracts me to discover technology I currently don't need or changes the order of units/buildings displayed in city production menu, making some units apparently 'disappear'.

Just note I play Civilization IV: Beyond the Sword, if that matters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't. You should just learn to ignore it completely, no other way apart from moding.